# cannot get xValue of AXIS-X on mschart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

i have a chart that i add values to it using datagridview. its xValues are persian date and i add them as string to AXIS-X but when i want to get those values on mouse_move event it returns an incorrect values. here is my code:
bool ismiddlebuttonclick = false;

```
    private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ismiddlebuttonclick)
        {
            label_VE.Visible = true;
            label_HO.Visible = true;
            label_VAL.Visible = true;

            label_HO.Location = new Point(76, e.Y);
            label_VE.Location = new Point(e.X, 21);

            if (e.X <= 83 || e.Y >= 435 || e.Y <= 27 || e.X >= 852)
            {
                label_VE.Visible = false;
                label_HO.Visible = false;
                label_VAL.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                label_VE.Visible = true;
                label_HO.Visible = true;
                label_VAL.Visible = true;
            }

            try
            {
                double yValue = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);
                double xPixel = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X));
                double xValue = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(xPixel);
                
                label_VAL.Text = string.Concat(Math.Round(yValue, 1).ToString(), " , ", xValue.ToString());
                label_VAL.Location = new Point(863, e.Y - 5);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("خطا در نشانگر" + ex.Message, "خطا", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            label_VE.Visible = false;
            label_HO.Visible = false;
            label_VAL.Visible = false;
            return;
        }


    }
```

i have tried to convert persian date to date time but my chart got deformation in that case i can see the correct xvalues on label_val.

Comment: _i add them as string_ which means that __the values are lost__. Always use the correct datatype if you care about the values. You need to convert probably to DateTime. Strings are all stored ass 0 (!!). only the labels show the values.